# How i can get user access token in Dialogflow?

Tags: laravel, dialogflow-es, chatbot, botman

I am trying to find the users access token in the dialogflow because I am trying to associate it with botman.io but it is not working
this is the code :

```
$botman = app('botman');
        
$dialogflow = Dialogflow::create('token')->listenForAction();

$botman->middleware->received($dialogflow);

$botman->hears('weathersearch', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();

    $bot->reply('I'm working');
})->middleware($dialogflow);
```

How can I find my token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:
https://github.com/genkovich/DialogFlowBotManMiddleware

I tried to write detailed instructions :)